# Having trouble setting flutter on windows

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I tried to set flutter on my computer with Windows OS. I installed Android Studio, Flutter SDK, Flutter and Dart plugins, and I want to run my apps on physical mobile device. But I do not know why I cant do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spWE1.png)

And this is the output of "flutter doctor" command:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vWrl.png)

Actually I do not know what to do next.

Comment: hi have you configured the sdk Path?

Comment: You should install Dart plugin and Flutter Plugin in android studio or any IDE that you use

Comment: yes, I did all of them